# Unable to retrieve values using loop in the testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Error:i is not defined.

Unable to retrieve the values by using for loop in the testcafe throwing error as 'i' is not defined.

this.totalaab= Selector(()=>document.querySelectorAll('aab-product-tile'));

```
 async verifyvale() {
        const accountcount = await this.totalaab.count;
        console.log(accountcount)
        for (let i = 0; i < accountcount; i++) {
          console.log(i);
          console.log(await Selector(() => document.querySelectorAll('aab-product-tile')));
          let overviewvalue = Selector(() => document.querySelectorAll('aab-product-tile')[i].shadowRoot.querySelector('.m-0.overflow-ellipsis.title-label.text-truncate.text-green.font-weight-500'));
          console.log(await overviewvalue.innerText);
          //await t.expect(await overviewvalue(i).exists).ok();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use the `i` variable inside the Selector function. If you want to query an element by its index, you can use the `nth` method as described at [Selector.nth Method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402748/reference/test-api/selector/nth?search#header).